# How to solve "500 server error" in Twitter card validater?

Tags: twitter, twitter-card

I am getting "500 internal server Error" from card validater  Trying to validate my webpage.

I am using the following summary card in head section of my document

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="$row['summary']" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@me" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="$row['title']" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="$row['description']" />
```

But it doesn't display summary card, I read the twitter card documentation , followed each staps and created a robot.txt file with the following contents :

```
User-agent:Twitterbot
Disallow :* 
Allow :/webpage
```

But it still doesn't work. Card validater is returning the same error. My domain is on a free live server http://000webhost.com so I don't have access to the error.log life.

Can you help me solve this issue?

Comment: What is the URL that you are trying to validate?

Answer (score 1):

Is it an CMS or raw html/php? Sometime very slow host generate various error for Twitter Validator. I will suggest try using an internal link, that you could view properly, and the source shows all card meta properly. If you are using WordPress, I would have suggested using free plugin [Twitter Cards Meta](https://wpdeveloper.net/free-plugin/twitter-cards-meta/). It does all the coding part and direct you step by step for validation.